# silly simple question in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have a line in my model in rails 2

named_scope :ordered, lambda {|*args| {:order => (args.first || 'created_at DESC')} }

how to change this to rails3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :ordered, lambda { |*args|
  order(args.first || 'created_at DESC')
}
```